# Increase max number of allowed tags on this site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, asking-questions

When asking for recommendations, I often find I use up most of my tags on categorization along several common dimensions. For example: linux, gui, gratis, open-source - that's already four tags before I actually said something about what the app I'm looking for does.

I therefore suggest we(/you) consider increasing the maximum number of tags on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com to at least 6.

Comment: You're barking at the wrong tree. First, we cannot do this (so you had to ask "upstream" at Meta.SE) – and second the idea is to "narrow down", not to "widen up". So I'm afraid the answer will be "no" there as well.

Comment: @Izzy: I think there's an "epistemological issue" here. The thing is, tags at the same time "widen" and "narrow". They widen because you can find the same question by single-tag search of more tags. But they also narrow if you interpret them in an intersectional sense, i.e.: An app that is all of: Linux, GUI, gratis, open-source and say audio-related. My motivation is for the narrowing interpretation.

Comment: Yes, understood. Still that's nothing we at SoftwareRecs.SE can do anything about. Site features etc. are not maintained by us; you need to head over to Meta.SE for that. Do a check first: I wouldn't be surprised if a similar question already exists there. (PS: the downvote isn't mine)